# module 'pandas' has no attribute 'expanding_max'

Tags: python, pandas

I want to calculate the max of previous rows using `pd.expanding_max()`. But it report module `'pandas'` has no attribute `'expanding_max'`

```
df['max2here'] = pd.expanding_max(df['a'])
```

> AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'expanding_max'

Comment: Maybe you should use [`cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cummax.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pd.expanding` family of functions have been deprecated and removed in recent versions (since v0.18, see the [GitHub commit](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/11603)), and replaced by the [expanding](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.expanding.html) API.

---

Change

```
pd.expanding_max(df['a'])
```

to use [**`Series.cummax`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cummax.html)

```
df['a'].cummax()
```

This operation can also be specified by using

```
df['a'].expanding().max()
```

But `cummax` is more optimised for cumulative max operation.